# Already having a decision tree model with binary class, how can I get a probability when i test a new instance?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I hava construct a decision tree model for a binary classification problem. What is bothering me is that when i have a new test instance, how can i get the probability or score which it belongs to.(not the specific classify result)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way can be to use the frequencies attached to the leaves, but this frequentist approach suffers from issues related to data quantities, so you can smooth those estimates in [various ways](http://www3.nd.edu/~dial/papers/AAAI06.pdf).

Also, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854710/c4-5-decision-tree-classification-probability-distribution) about C4.5.